# JSON only prints last object in array

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to make custom json feed from my wordpress page. The problem is the loop seem to overwrite every object, so it only prints the last object as json. i've also tried moving the echo inside the loop, but then it does not looks probably formatted in the browser.

here is my code:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $r = str_replace("\n",'', shorten_txt($post->post_content, 500));
    $n = str_replace("\r", '', $r);
    $post_data = array(
    'title' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'link' => get_permalink($post->ID),
    'image' => catch_that_image(),
    'content' => $n,
    'time' => strtotime($post->post_date_gmt));

     $data = (array('item' => $post_data));



}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of `$data` is happening within the `foreach`, which means it will be re-initialized everytime the value is assigned to it. I am not sure if you have done this by mistake or if you were not sure on how to do this.

Try this

```
$data = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $r = str_replace("\n",'', shorten_txt($post->post_content, 500));
    $n = str_replace("\r", '', $r);
    $post_data = array(
    'title' => get_the_title($post->ID),
    'link' => get_permalink($post->ID),
    'image' => catch_that_image(),
    'content' => $n,
    'time' => strtotime($post->post_date_gmt));
     $data[] = (array('item' => $post_data));

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

What this does is, it is declaring the `$data` variable outside of the `foreach` loop and the assignment is pushed to this array. Hope this helps.